# Is there a good and free software to backup a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a software or script to make a daily backup (automatic) of a mysql database.
Any suggestions?

Right now my solution is to use Mysql workbench with mysql dump, but I have to do it manually, so anything free and automatic would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html) details various backup types. But if you just want it automatically, make it a scheduled task or a cron job. That's what those services are for.

Comment: I really don't know scheduled tasks, do you have any documentation on that by any chance?

Comment: You can try [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx). In any case, just create a batch file (not needed if your backup command fits in a single line) that you schedule to run every week or day or so. You can find the task scheduler by typing "task scheduler" into the start menu.